# PDO When do i need to parametire my queries?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement, sql-injection

So I am using PDO to try and be safe against SQL injections.

My question is should I check/verify my database information before using it?

For example:

```
$stmt = $pdo -> prepare(SELECT userID FROM user, comment WHERE userNumber ='1' AND user.userName = comment.UserName");
```

The option I think I have are:

1) I validate ALL input before I insert it in my database, so I dont have to check if user.userName is string that can inject code.

2) I should parameterize data that I get from my database. Not sure yet, but something like:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':comment.UserName', comment.UserName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

3) Both validate and still parameterize.

*query made on the fly

Answer (score 1):

The rule is simple: **ALWAYS** parameterize your queries. Even if these queries are never used on a web page and face a malicious userbase, **ANYTIME** you use external data in a query string, even data that's come out of the database, you can **STILL** inject yourself.

The sole exceptions are the times when parametric queries won't work, e.g. arbitrary length `WHERE IN (...)` value lists, dynamic table/field names (which are usually a bad idea anyways). In these limited instances, you build the query yourself, but have to take appropriate injection attack mitigation procedures.

Comment: Just to make sure, in all clauses. Select, where, group by, etc since in all of time a "well" type string can inject code in the whole query? Will this make code many times larger?

Comment: consider a query sequence where you fetch a person's name from one table,and then use it in other queries. If that person is `Miles O'Brien`, you'll now be injecting a quote into the other queries and breaking them. Won't be long until little [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com) signs up for your system. Use parameters, and this problem goes away, no matter how much injectible stuff is within the data.